# How to shift focus up-down and left right using arrow keys in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

## `this code draws a 5x5 grid , I want to shift focus using arrow keys (up-down, left-right)`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("195x170")
root.title("Grid")
bgcolor = "#1a8cff"

#Draw Grid
for i in range(0,25,5):
    for j in range(0,25,5):
        e=tk.Entry(root,width=5,bg=bgcolor)
        e.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky="nsew",padx=1,pady=1,ipady=5)
        if bgcolor == "#1a8cff":
            bgcolor = "#66b3ff"
        else:
            bgcolor = "#1a8cff"

root.mainloop()
```

I want to shift focus(cursor) from one cell to another, i.e up-down, left-right using arrow keys
please help me with the code....
I tried .focus() and bind but that only works for up and down, I want to move 3-d

Comment: Include the code that using the arrow keys so that we can identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with keyboard focusing on widgets.

1. Decoding keyboard input into focus movement (k_table).
2. Constructing a matrix so that individual widgets are accessible (store).
3. Limiting unwanted control (Tab key).
4. Enabling button selection of widget whilst maintaining row, column values (press).
5. Displaying widget contents oncommand (select).

This code handles all these issues.

It works on Window 10, python 3.9.1

```py
import tkinter as tk

k_table = dict(
    Down  = lambda y: y,
    Up    = lambda y: - y,
    Right = lambda y: 1 - y,
    Left  = lambda y: y - 1)

pr, pc, store = 0, 0, []

def select(event):
    print(event.widget.get())

def press(event):
    global pr, pc
    entry = event.widget.grid_info()
    pr, pc = entry["row"], entry["column"]
    store[pr][pc].focus_set()

def makepad(w, h):
    for row in range(h):
        store.append([])
        for col in range(w):
            b = tk.Entry(app, width = 10)
            b.grid(row = row, column = col)
            b.bind("<Button-1>", press)
            b.bind("<Return>", select)
            store[row].append(b)

    app.focus_set()
    store[0][0].focus_set()

def scroller(event):
    global pr, pc
    ja = k_table[event.keysym] # return lambda ja
    ipr, ipc = pr + ja(1), pc + ja(0)
    if ipr > -1 and ipr < h and ipc > -1 and ipc < w:
        pr, pc = ipr, ipc
        store[pr][pc].focus_set()
        store[pr][pc].select_range(0, "end")

def dummy(event):
    return "break"

app = tk.Tk()
w, h = 5, 5
# make a 5x5 matrix of buttons
makepad(w, h)
# bind keyboard input to function scroller
app.event_add("<<AAA>>", "<Up>", "<Down>", "<Left>", "<Right>")
app.bind("<<AAA>>", scroller)
# disable all <Key-Tab> except for <Alt-Tab>
app.bind("<Tab>", dummy)
app.mainloop()
```